Are dealership car batteries actually higher quality than aftermarket batteries?
Generally speaking.
I'm thinking something like the True Start brand batteries sold by Toyota at the dealership.
Sometimes they're even cheaper than the aftermarket batteries at AutoZone, so I thought about getting one.
Are the dealer batteries actually better quality?

Subaru went thru a period of faulty new batteries and the problem seems resolved but never fully explained. Subaru buys from battery manufacturers like most. unfortunately, Subaru's telematics (Starlink) cellular system was also implicated in premature battery failures. GM suffered a similar failure with their OnStar system. All corrected. Compare dealer batteries, presumed marked up, against aftermarket for; price, capacity, warranty to make a judgement. You must also consider regular flooded, enhanced flooded, and AGM batteries. You get what you pay for applies to car batteries.

They are probably the same, down to the luck factor that is always present with the batteries.
Toyota does not make batteries, neither do VW or Ford. They just order them branded from the lowest bidding battery company.
If you want something of a higher lifespan and reliability, try a deep cycle battery. But, their prices are higher by a factor of at least 2.5 .

Deep cycle batteries aren't meant for use as an automotive starting battery. They don't have the output (hot/cold cranking amps) of an automotive battery for the size factor, but they do last longer as you suggest.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in regard to cranking amps: not true in the recent 15 or 20 years.

I think you missed one point of my statement, the "size factor". Ounce for ounce the deep cycle is not going to compete with a regular car battery when it comes to CCA.

Most of the time, yes! Dealership batteries can be of better quality because they are usually offered under the car manufacturer’s official brand and are built to specific standards.
However, overall, there shouldn’t be a significant difference compared to aftermarket batteries, as they are often made by the same manufacturers with only different branding and packaging. If the dealership offers a good price and you value a reliable warranty, it might be a better option.

On the other hand, the dealership batteries often spend a lot on the shelves before they are considered worth a discount. The main purpose dealerships keep batteries stockpiled is not selling them for profit (they pretty much do sell them for profit anyway), but to meet a sudden surge of warranty claims for new-ish cars. The lead-acid technology (and market!) sometimes do create such surges, esp. in November and December (oozies probably get them in June instead). If the RMA rate gets overestimated for some period, the somewhat aged, but still good as new batteries are dumped.
